# Information not showing after clicking on dynamic button (Using Toggle)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to display some additional information after clicking on "More Info" button.

First the div is dynamically generated based on my database. Which div contains a "more info" button which when clicked should show more information. However, only the first button works and when clicked, all "more info" from all the generated div's are shown.

I want to only the more info related to the div I'm clicking on to be shown/hidden, while the others still hidden.

**This is the HTML/PHP**

```
<div id="event_info">
   <img src= "<?php echo $row['img'];?> "/>
   <div class="event_description">
      <h1><?php echo $row['gathering_name'];?></h1>
      <b>Hosted By:</b> <?php echo $row['event_host'];?> </br>
      <b>Location:</b> <?php echo $row['city'].', '. $row['state']; ?></br>
      <b>Date:</b> <?php $event_date = strtotime($row['event_start']);
         echo date("F jS, Y" , $event_date);?></br></br>
      <!-- MORE INFO ABOUT THE GATHERINGS -->
      <button class="findButton2" id="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">MORE INFO</button>
      <div id="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" class="event_moreinfo">
         <?php echo $row['description'];?></br>
         <b>Gym Name: </b> <?php echo $row['gym_name'];?> </br>
         <b>Gym Address: </b>  <?php echo $row['street_address'];?></br>
         <?php echo $row['city'].', '.$row['state'].', '. $row['country'];?></br>
         <b>Nearest Airport: </b> <?php echo $row['nearest_airport'];?></br>
         <b>Expected Attendance: </b> <?php echo $row['attendance']; ?></br>
         <b>Average Ticket Cost: </b> <?php echo $row['event_cost']; ?> </br>
         <b>Contact: </b> <a href = "mailto:<?php echo $row['host_email'];?>"> Host Email</a>               
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**This is my script (jQuery)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var event_id = $(".findButton2").attr("id");
    $('#' + event_id).on('click', function() {
        $(".event_moreinfo").toggle(1000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happen because all dynamic div have same class name `event_moreinfo`. Use `this` with `next` to `toogle` your `div` like below. It's only toggle your next div which have class `event_moreinfo` when button is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var event_id = $(".findButton2").attr("id");
    $('#' + event_id).on('click', function() {
        $(this).next(".event_moreinfo").toggle(1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That worked perfectly for the first generated div but the other divs still don't work unfortunately.

Comment: It's because you get `findButton2` id. Get ID dynamically when button lick and it's work.

Comment: I'm kind confused. Isn't that what I'm doing with the var event_id?

Comment: hey man! you are the best!!! THANK YOU! IT WORKED!! I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have same ID for multiple elements, while IDs are supposed to be unique. And I guess this is true for the whole document and one of the reason your code might not work as expected. Also, you are dynamically generating the divs, so you’d better delegate binding one ancestor, to be sure that any click on any child div is triggered. Let’s say that all this divs are direct children of a `<div class=“event_table”>` element, then

```
$(‘.event_table’).on(‘click’, ‘.event_info’, function () { 
    $(‘this’).find(‘.event_moreinfo’).toggle(1000);
});
```

will be able to correctly identify the element where user has clicked.

More info on the matter over at the [JQuery official documentation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: That didn't work as well. But I will read more about the documentation. Thank you so much for the help